# Sub string search like "LIKE" keyword in SQL

Tags: cassandra

I'm using apache-cassandra 1.2 (CLI version), I want to search a sub string in columns, just like we search in SQL using like or where clause.
Can anyone tell me how to search a sub string in rows?
I only want to do it in CLI, please don's suggest CQL cassandra.

Comment: forget about CLI or CQLSH, **LIKE** keyword like anything is not supported in Cassandra. If you just google properly, you will get information, so many similar threads are there. No need to ask again

Comment: then can u tell me how to search a sub string cassandra

Comment: best approach will be using apache solr

Comment: we have to use cassandra.
Any other idea???

Comment: You can integrate Cassandra with Solr.  Check out DataStax Enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if cassandra supports indexing on collection columns in near future, it will be very much possible. In that case we can defragment the text into pieces and easily perform the like operation.

But for now the best you can do is prefix, if your order is alphabetical. For example I have a CF with comparator UTF8Type, and then I can do slice query and bring all columns that start with the prefix, and end with the prefix where you replace the last char with the next one in order (i.e. "aaa"-"aab")